# How to find the installed application on windows 10

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing windows app and i have side-loaded the app. For some debugging purpose i need to inspect the installation directory.

I looked for it in below directory but can't see it there.

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

Where are the windows 10 apps installed on drive?

Comment: To determine the location programmatically, use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`. If you just want to dig it out for debugging, then from PowerShell type `Get-AppxPackage -Name YourPackageName` and it will show a bunch of stuff including the `InstalledLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your application data in the following path ..

```
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\(Your packageName)
```

The package name is usually somewhat like this *"Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy"..* you will need to identify your package accordingly..

Comment: I can get the application data from there. But i where the app is actually installed? The folder you mentioned has nothing in it. I already use that directory for accessing user data.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Searching for the keyword "Cortana" in the system drive did show some unpackaged files for x86,AMD64 and other cpu architecture but I don't think the actual package files are accessible for an UWP app..